# When running a Gulp task, it doesn't seem to recognize files it created

Tags: gulp

I have two tasks in my Gulp file:

1. **default** Uses LESS to merge a bunch of files together with comments and sourcemapping.
2. **prepare** Grabs the CSS file generated by #1 and cleans / compresses it.

I've told Gulp that task #2 requires task #1.

When I run task #2, the files are created for task #1, but the files that should be created for task #2 are not. If I run task #2 again, then the files for task #2 are created.

I'm thinking there's some sort of cache Gulp is using, and since the files didn't exist when Gulp first ran, it isn't finding them and therefore not doing anything with them.

I've tried searching around to no avail. Any thoughts or suggestions would be great!

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso');

gulp.task( 'default', ['styles-dev'], function() {} );
gulp.task( 'prepare', ['minify-css'], function() {} )

gulp.task('styles-dev', function() {
  gulp
    .src("source/styles/global*.less")
    .pipe( less({
      sourceMap: true
    }) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest("build/local/styles") )
});

gulp.task('minify-css', ['styles-dev'], function() {
  gulp.src('build/local/styles/*.css')
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/pre/styles'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('styles-dev', function() {
  return gulp
    .src("source/styles/global*.less")
    .pipe( less({
      sourceMap: true
    }) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest("build/local/styles") )
});
```

Looks like I need to return the stream as a "hint" that the task is finished. It's amazing how asking a question will help you find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso');

gulp.task( 'default', ['css']);

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src("source/styles/global*.less")
    .pipe( less({
      sourceMap: true
    }) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/local/styles"))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/pre/styles'));
});
```